# Binding Generic Xml to Datagrid

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, binding, datagrid

I have a collection of xml-files.
the files are always built like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
  <Row>
    <halfproducten ID="105">Digitale bestanden van papieren zeekaarten en 1800 serie</halfproducten>
    <formaat ID="106">PDF, PS, SHAPE, CARIS NTX/ASCII*, GEOTIFF, S57*</formaat>
    <datum_validiteit ID="107">Meest recente editie</datum_validiteit>
    <geografische_grenzen ID="108">Karteringsgebied</geografische_grenzen>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <halfproducten ID="109">Fragmenten van bovengenoemde bestanden</halfproducten>
    <formaat ID="110">PDF, PS, SHAPE, CARIS NTX/ASCII*, GEOTIFF, S57*</formaat>
    <datum_validiteit ID="111">Meest recente editie</datum_validiteit>
    <geografische_grenzen ID="112">Karteringsgebied</geografische_grenzen>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <halfproducten ID="113">Minuutbladen</halfproducten>
    <formaat ID="114">Papier</formaat>
    <datum_validiteit ID="115">
    </datum_validiteit>
    <geografische_grenzen ID="116">Karteringsgebied</geografische_grenzen>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <halfproducten ID="117">Tracings</halfproducten>
    <formaat ID="118">PDF</formaat>
    <datum_validiteit ID="119">Meest recent</datum_validiteit>
    <geografische_grenzen ID="120">Karteringsgebied</geografische_grenzen>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <halfproducten ID="121">Bathymetrie-bestanden</halfproducten>
    <formaat ID="122">ASCII, x-y-z (20 x 20)</formaat>
    <datum_validiteit ID="123">Meest recent</datum_validiteit>
    <geografische_grenzen ID="124">Karteringsgebied</geografische_grenzen>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <halfproducten ID="125">Object-selecties data bestanden:;Wrakken/Obstructies;Lichten;Boorplatforms/Boorputten;Boeien/Bakens</halfproducten>
    <formaat ID="126">Papier, ASCII, HOB, S57, SHAPE, GEOTIFF, GML</formaat>
    <datum_validiteit ID="127">Actueel</datum_validiteit>
    <geografische_grenzen ID="128">Nederlands Continentaal Plat + Territoriale zee</geografische_grenzen>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <halfproducten ID="129">Maritieme (zone)grenzen (UNCLOS)</halfproducten>
    <formaat ID="130">ASCII, SHAPE, KML</formaat>
    <datum_validiteit ID="131">Actueel</datum_validiteit>
    <geografische_grenzen ID="132">Continentaal Plat + Territoriale zee van Nederland, het Caraibisch deel van het Koninkrijk der Nederlanden</geografische_grenzen>
  </Row>
</Data>
```

Here the Data and row elements are always present, the tag elements are always different tagnames and the amount of tags is always different.
Only the Row elements all have the same children only different innertext.

I would like to Bind this xml-file to my DataGrid so that if somthing is changed in the DataGrid it automatically changes in the xml file.

So far i have this:

```
<Grid.DataContext>
<XmlDataProvider x:Name="xmlDataProvider"/>
</Grid.DataContext>
```

(My DataGrid is in the Grid)

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="DataGridXml" SelectionMode="Extended"
SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" CanUserSortColumns="False"
CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
```

CodeBehind:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(path);
XmlDataProvider dataProvider = xmlDataProvider;
dataProvider.Document = xmlDoc;
dataProvider.XPath = "Data/Row";
```

With all of the above code my solution works, it also binds to my datagrid, only it is binding to the properties of the Xml-Element  and not binding the tags to the columns.

So to be clear, what i want is this:

```
__________________________________________
|     Tag1    |    Tag2     |    Tag3     |
|-------------|-------------|-------------|
|Lerum Ipsum11|Lerum Ipsum12|Lerum Ipsum13|
|-------------|-------------|-------------|
|Lerum Ipsum21|Lerum Ipsum22|Lerum Ipsum23|
|-------------|-------------|-------------|
```

Thanks in advance for helping me ;)

Comment: Use a DataSet : DataSet ds = new DataSet(); ds.ReadXml(path);  dataProvider dataProvider = ds.Tables[0];

Comment: I'll try that, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DataGird` Column Definition like:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Name="DataGridXml" SelectionMode="Extended" DataContext="{Binding dataProvider}"
            SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" CanUserSortColumns="False"
            CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
            VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/Data/Row}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tag1" Binding="{Binding XPath=tag1/.}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tag2" Binding="{Binding XPath=tag2/.}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tag3" Binding="{Binding XPath=tag3/.}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

***OUTPUT:***

[image: XML Bind]

***PS: I've also changed that `DataContext` assignment and `AutoGenerateColumn` property. And making the `dataProvider` a `property`, which is a method variable in your code behind.***

***Update: If want to generate the `DataGrid` `Columns` from `XML`***

***XMAL:***

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Name="DataGridXml" SelectionMode="Extended" DataContext="{Binding dataProvider}"
        SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" CanUserSortColumns="False"
        CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
        VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
        local:XMLToColumn.GenerateColumnForGrid="True"/>
```

***Attached Behavior:***

```
public class XMLToColumn
{
    public static bool GetGenerateColumnForGrid(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(GenerateColumnForGridProperty);
    }

    public static void SetGenerateColumnForGrid(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(GenerateColumnForGridProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for GenerateColumnForGrid.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty GenerateColumnForGridProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("GenerateColumnForGrid", typeof(bool), typeof(XMLToColumn), new PropertyMetadata(GenerateColumnForGridChanged));

    public static void GenerateColumnForGridChanged(DependencyObject DO, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataGrid = DO as DataGrid;
        if (dataGrid != null && Convert.ToBoolean(e.NewValue) == true)
        {
            dataGrid.Loaded += dataGrid_Loaded;
        }
    }

    static void dataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
        if (dataGrid != null)
        {
            dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
            var dataprovider = dataGrid.DataContext as XmlDataProvider;
            if (dataprovider != null)
            {
                var mainNode = dataprovider.Document.SelectSingleNode(dataprovider.XPath);
                foreach (var item in mainNode.ChildNodes)
                {
                    var node=item as XmlNode;
                    var column = new DataGridTextColumn();
                    column.Binding = new Binding() { XPath = node.Name+"/." };
                    column.Header = node.Name;
                    dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

***Output:***

[image: XML]

***update for ID problem:***

```
public class XMLToColumn
{
    public static bool GetGenerateColumnForGrid(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(GenerateColumnForGridProperty);
    }

    public static void SetGenerateColumnForGrid(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(GenerateColumnForGridProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for GenerateColumnForGrid.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty GenerateColumnForGridProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("GenerateColumnForGrid", typeof(bool), typeof(XMLToColumn), new PropertyMetadata(GenerateColumnForGridChanged));

    public static void GenerateColumnForGridChanged(DependencyObject DO, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataGrid = DO as DataGrid;
        if (dataGrid != null && Convert.ToBoolean(e.NewValue) == true)
        {
            dataGrid.Loaded += dataGrid_Loaded;               
            dataGrid.RowEditEnding += new EventHandler<DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs>(dataGrid_RowEditEnding);
        }
    }

    static void dataGrid_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
         var dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
         if (dataGrid != null)
         {                 
             var dataprovider = dataGrid.DataContext as XmlDataProvider;
             if (dataprovider != null)
             {
                 if (e.Row.GetIndex() == dataGrid.Items.Count - 1)
                 {
                     int maxID = Convert.ToInt32(dataprovider.Document.LastChild.LastChild.LastChild.Attributes["ID"].Value);
                     var rowElement = dataprovider.Document.CreateElement("Row");
                     foreach (var col in dataGrid.Columns)
                     {
                         var childElement = dataprovider.Document.CreateElement(col.Header.ToString());
                         childElement.SetAttribute("ID",(++maxID).ToString());
                         rowElement.AppendChild(childElement);                             
                     }
                     dataprovider.Document.DocumentElement.AppendChild(rowElement);
                     e.Cancel = true;
                 }
             }
         }            
    }        

    static void dataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
        if (dataGrid != null)
        {
            dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
            var dataprovider = dataGrid.DataContext as XmlDataProvider;
            if (dataprovider != null)
            {
                var mainNode = dataprovider.Document.SelectSingleNode(dataprovider.XPath);
                foreach (var item in mainNode.ChildNodes)
                {
                    var node = item as XmlNode;
                    var column = new DataGridTextColumn();
                    column.Binding = new Binding() { XPath = node.Name + "/." };
                    column.Header = node.Name;
                    dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

As soon as you end editing of last cell of last row the behavior will add a new `row` in your `datagrid`. Also code is very dependent on your `XML` stricture. Please have a close look.

***output:***

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Only the thing is that this time the xml-file had 3 "Columns", but another file could have 15 columns.
So i can't define the columns in xaml like that..

Comment: @NickGames ok I understand. Would it be OK for you If i post a new solution with attached behavior to generate grid columns? Or you don't want any c# code solution?

Comment: Thanks for the response! That would be really nice, thank you!

Comment: That is a really nice solution! Thanks for all the effort! I will accept your answer, but i have only one question left. Every child element of the row node now had an unique ID as an attribute. I want to be able to insert a new row or a new column and generate id's for each new node that gets created. When a new row gets inserted somewhere between two other rows, i want it to be added at that position in the xml too. Is that possible this way?

Comment: @NickGames you can't add rows in datagrid directly settings (not without very tricky code). We need to add row in our XML document which will reflected to datagrid and the ID logic can be placed there. hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks! I already do that in my code now. But do i have to refresh my datagrid to see the changes? or do i have to somehow refresh my DataProvider?

Comment: @NickGames neither , new rows will automatically get reflected to grid.